# Deploy React Project in Firebase Hosting

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

I wrote a project with React.js and I want to deploy it in Firebase hosting but I get the following error:

> Error: Failed to list Firebase projects. See firebase-debug.log for more info.

firebase-debug.log:

```
[debug] [2022-06-03T14:11:04.642Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] [2022-06-03T14:11:04.646Z] Command:       /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/firebase init
[debug] [2022-06-03T14:11:04.647Z] CLI Version:   11.0.1
[debug] [2022-06-03T14:11:04.648Z] Platform:      linux
[debug] [2022-06-03T14:11:04.648Z] Node Version:  v16.14.0
[debug] [2022-06-03T14:11:04.649Z] Time:          Fri Jun 03 2022 10:11:04 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
[debug] [2022-06-03T14:11:04.649Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] 
[debug] [2022-06-03T14:11:04.656Z] >>> [apiv2][query] GET https://firebase-public.firebaseio.com/cli.json [none]
[debug] [2022-06-03T14:11:04.697Z] > command requires scopes: ["email","openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
[debug] [2022-06-03T14:11:04.698Z] > authorizing via signed-in user (abc.sadeghi27@gmail.com)
[info] 
     ######## #### ########  ######## ########     ###     ######  ########
     ##        ##  ##     ## ##       ##     ##  ##   ##  ##       ##
     ######    ##  ########  ######   ########  #########  ######  ######
     ##        ##  ##    ##  ##       ##     ## ##     ##       ## ##
     ##       #### ##     ## ######## ########  ##     ##  ######  ########

You're about to initialize a Firebase project in this directory:

  /home/ali27/Desktop/Project/Resume/react-site

[info] 
=== Project Setup
[info] 
[info] First, let's associate this project directory with a Firebase project.
[info] You can create multiple project aliases by running firebase use --add, 
[info] but for now we'll just set up a default project.
[info] 
[debug] [2022-06-03T14:11:10.062Z] >>> [apiv2][query] GET https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects pageSize=100
[debug] [2022-06-03T14:11:11.166Z] <<< [apiv2][status] GET https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects 403
[debug] [2022-06-03T14:11:11.167Z] <<< [apiv2][body] GET https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects [omitted]
[debug] [2022-06-03T14:11:11.167Z] Unable to parse JSON: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
[debug] [2022-06-03T14:11:11.719Z] FirebaseError: Unable to parse JSON: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at RetryOperation._fn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/apiv2.js:258:39)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
[error] 
[error] Error: Failed to list Firebase projects. See firebase-debug.log for more info.
```

Thank you for solving my problem.

Comment: I'm guessing that the output you provided is the result of "firebase init". You are getting 403 there... did you run "firebase login" before init? do you have permissions? which firebase plan are you using?

Answer (score 0):

your session might be expired. Try re-authenticating, use the following command;

`firebase login:add`